# Alternative to "since when" that asks about time instead of expressing sarcasm, annoyment or doubt

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the last few days, I have been posting questions such as “Since when is El Cantar de mio Cid considered a national epic of Spain?”, “Since when is Daredevils of Sassoun considered a national epic of the Armenians?” and “Since when is the Ramakien considered one of Thailand's national epics?” on Literature Stack Exchange. These are history-of-literature questions asking for date or time periods.

Today, someone commented,

> I'm a little confused by the titles of these recent questions of yours. Are you using the phrase "since when" in [its usual idiomatic meaning](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/since%20when)?

I am not using “since when” in the way defined by Merriam-Webster:

> used to show that one is surprised and often angry, annoyed, or doubtful about what someone has said or done

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/since_when) defines “since when” as “From what time”, so I went looking for usage examples of that phrase. Curiously, the [DuckDuckGo results for “from what time”](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22from+what+time%22&t=ffab&ia=web) returns only pages in which that specific phrase isn't even used.

So I'm still looking for an alternative to “since when” that would work in British English (!) in questions such as

> [Since when] is El Cantar de mio Cid considered a national epic of Spain?

Does “from what time” really work in spite of my inability to find usage examples? If not, what phrase would appropriate here?

Comment: The last question in your post, "what phrase would work better", is going to invite not-great answers.  There are probably a lot of equally good alternatives ("when was X first considered", "when did X become", "how long has it been since X", "when was the first time that X", etc.), which doesn't suit the Stack Exchange format.

Comment: "... delete your question". Ah, the kind people of English SE :-D

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't suggesting you delete this question.  I think much of it is useful, just not that last part.  I don't have an answer to the question, "Is 'since when' always skeptical", but I think it's a good question.

Comment: "How long did it take for *El Cantar de mio Cid* to be generally accepted as a national epic of Spain?” / I hope you'll take a look at ELL before completely rejecting it. ELL has a lot to offer. / Voting to close because this question amounts to a request for help with proofreading.

Comment: I was being kind by hinting at an answer — which is against the rules — rather than just voting to close. I will be cruel (to be kind) and suggest that the basic nature of your question makes it unsuitable for SE EL&U, as is obvious if you read the [Tour], and that you would be kind to the standards of this list if you posted on English Language Learners instead. I have deleted my comment, because I should not have indicated the answer.

Comment: Yeah, "since when" means "from what time" as well as "what? that's crap!". They're clearly distinguished by tone in spoken English. In text you need to be a bit more careful, unfortunately.

Comment: @David "as is obvious if you read the Tour". I disagree. How does my question not fit into "Word choice and usage", which is listed as within the site's scope? I also don't see how my question fits any of the types of questions under "don’t ask any questions about the following topic" in the [Help Centre](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: "English Language & Usage Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts."  And then when you compose an answer the column on the right says "If your question is about learning English, ask it on ELL instead." Simple expressions of time relate to "learning English", either as a non-native speaker (at whatever level) or a native speaker with a limited education.

Comment: @David Your interpretation is IMO excessively broad; and this question,  being about subtle shades of meaning depending on context, is entirely appropriate for ELU.

Comment: @Spencer You are entitled to your opinion. I regard mine as based on a literal interpretation of the purpose of this site. Never mind the width, read the words. And ask yourself, why did they set up English Language Learners?

Comment: @David ELL is for simple subjects at a basic learner's level, which this decidedly is **not**.

Comment: @Spencer …and "When was El Cid first considered…" or "How long has El Cid been considered…" are not basic learner level? The fact that time expressions of this sort are a difficulty when learning different European languages because of the structure and tenses  used does not mean that they are not basic. (Likewise the deficiencies of poorly educated native speakers.)

Comment: @David Even a well-educated English speaker can give offense with a careless choice of words and/or phrasing. *That* is the subject of this question, not the details of any answers.

Comment: Unfortunately the focus of this question (and, consequently, of the answers) on finding the alternatives has rendered it subject to closing as too trivial. Behind it there, however, lurks a more interesting question that would be within the scope of this site: has the use of *since when* in rhetorical questions become so widespread that it has become impossible to use it in genuine requests of information? If so, since when has that been impossible?

Answer (score 8):

I can think of a few ways.

The simplest:

> When was *El Cantar de mio Cid* first considered a national epic of
> Spain?

(One could say, in lieu of "considered", "recognized" or "declared")

A little more wordy:

> When did *El Cantar de mio Cid* first start to be considered a
> national epic of Spain?

Comment: "When was El Cantar de mio Cid first considered a national epic of Spain?" Doesn't that imply that it no longer is?

Comment: @Tsundoku No, the use of "first" implies continuation.

Comment: @Spencer:  It implies continuation but it doesn't necessarily imply continuation to the present.  The question "When did Babe Ruth first play baseball?" implies that he played baseball for a while but it doesn't imply that he is still playing baseball.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert  It also doesn't imply non-continuation to the present.  If the distinction were important in context (there's that word again), another sentence would be added to clarify.

Comment: @Spencer:  Fair.  I just didn't want the OP to think that it definitively implied one or the other.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be

> How long has *El Cantar de mio Cid* been considered a national epic of Spain?

This has the advantage of sounding natural and being clear that you are discussing an ongoing (and accepted) status. The potential disadvantage is that you may get answers of the form "for [number] years" rather than "since [date]", and although these ought to be equivalent, in practice the former may be less precise.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be:

> **From when** was El Cantar de mio Cid considered a national epic of Spain?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest suggestion, for objective fact:

- When did it **become** ...

If the question is more about opinion than objective fact:

- When was it first **recognized as** ...
- When did it **enter the canon** of ...